# to_datetime - max function returns the wrong max date

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have data which it comes from a csv file, and I am trying to get the max date.

**Data:**

```
0    01/01/1994
1    01/01/1994
2    01/01/1994
3    01/01/1994
4    01/01/1994
.
.
.
970075    31/08/2021
970076    31/08/2021
970077    31/08/2021
970078    31/08/2021
970079    31/08/2021
```

However, I get the wrong max value. It seems that my code sets as string my date column, and not as date format, even though I  set to_datetime. Because of that, I use `re` on that string to get the year.

**My code:**

```
file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Date'], errors = 'coerce',
                dayfirst = True, format = '%d.%m.%Y'
                ).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')


print(file['Date'].min(), file['Date'].max(), range(int(re.search(r'(\d{4})', file['Date'].min()).group()), int(re.search(r'(\d{4})', file['Date'].max()).group())))
```

**Returns:**

```
01/01/1994 31/12/2020 range(1994, 2020)
```

I would like to get the max `31/08/2021` and not `31/12/2020`.

Comment: I feel like you're comparing the strings and not the dates, and of course `'31/12...' > '31/08...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.dt.strftime` for converting datetimes to strings repr.

```
.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

You can convert to custom format after `min` and `max`.

All together, also simplify for get maximal and minimal years:

```
file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Date'], errors = 'coerce', dayfirst = True)
years = file['Date'].dt.year

print(file['Date'].min().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), 
      file['Date'].max().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), 
      range(years.min(), years.max()))

01/01/1994 31/08/2021 range(1994, 2021)
```

Comment: It works!! however after that, I make a for: 
`for yearX in range(years.min(), years.max()):
    include_data = file[years == yearX]
    print(yearX)` 
and it returns 2020 as the last year... Why?

Comment: @SultryT. - need `for yearX in range(years.min(), years.max() + 1)`, if check e.g. [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp), stop value is not included

Comment: Mmmm, ok!! It is not because the `dt.year` configuration. Silly mistake of my, thank you.